# Caret size is different after certain letters

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-textbox

I have noticed a subtle difference in caret thickness within a WPF TextBox depending on the window size. This occurs when the TextBox is inside a different element. The caret is twice as wide after some letters. It is somewhat subtle, but I am wondering if anyone has any thoughts about this or guesses as to why it is rendering this way.

I created a simple window to repeat the effect with this code:

```
<Grid Width="500" Height="50">
    <Viewbox>
        <TextBox Width="400" Height="30" Foreground="Black" FontSize="18"/>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

[Caret after the letter T](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmIWZ.jpg)

[Caret after the letter R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JB6CW.jpg)

(I don't have the reputation to post images yet)

Comment: Why do you need ViewBox there?

Comment: The ViewBox is needed in this example to recreate the problem in my application (which has a TextBox within some other elements). Without it there is no caret issue.

Comment: Side-note for '_I don't have the reputation to post images yet_'. Your images are of unsupported format.